# DBMS_DATAPUMP error: The current API cannot be executed because of inconsistencies between the API and the current definition of the job

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, amazon-rds, impdp

I'm trying to do an `impdp` on a Amazon RDS Oracle instance using `DBMS_DATAPUMP`.

I'm following the steps described [in the Amazon RDS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html) (*Importing Data into Oracle on Amazon RDS*).

I've already copied successfully the dmp to the RDS instances.

This is my `impdp` job executed with `awssys` user:

```
-- IMPORT DATAPUMP
DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => '20180618_my_copied.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''MYSCHEMA'')');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
END;
/
```

I can't understand the meaning of the error displayed:

```
ORA-39002: operazione non valida
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 6224
ORA-06512: a line 7
39002. 00000 -  "invalid operation"
*Cause:    The current API cannot be executed because of inconsistencies
           between the API and the current definition of the job.
           Subsequent messages supplied by DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_STATUS
           will further describe the error.
*Action:   Modify the API call to be consistent with the current job or
           redefine the job in a manner that will support the specified API.
```

This is the version of the *source* DB:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

This is the version of Amazon RDS instance:

```
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

**EDIT:** I've added `version=COMPATIBLE` to both the `expdp` command and `DBMS_DATAPUMP` options but error remains.

```
expdp system@source_db version=COMPATIBLE dumpfile=20180618_my.dmp logfile=20180618_my.log directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR CONSISTENT=Y  SCHEMAS=MYSCHEMA,MYSCHEMA2,MYSCHEMA3,MYSCHEMA4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries I found this way:

1. Running `expdp`  with `version=11.2` parameter set.
2. Copy with `DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE` the dmp to the RDS Instance
3. Running `impdp`  with `version=11.2` parameter set from the 11.2 machine.

This causes:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39068: invalid master table data in row with PROCESS_ORDER=-1
ORA-01403: no data found
```

Following ORACLE support **IMPDP Raises ORA-39068: Invalid Master Table Data In Row With PROCESS_ORDER=-1 And ORA-1403 (Doc ID 1556555.1)** I successfully deleted the `DUAL` in excess.

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type, status
FROM dba_objects
WHERE object_name = 'DUAL'
AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE';

OWNER      OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE STATUS
---------- ----------- ----------- -------------
SYS        DUAL        TABLE       VALID
AWSSYS     DUAL        TABLE       VALID

DROP TABLE AWSSYS.DUAL;
```

By repeating step 3 `impdp` now works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your versions differ between source and destination.

```
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null, version=>'COMPATIBLE');
```

Oh, the bad news: you need this for the expdp too.

Comment: [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL870) say that `VERSION=COMPATIBLE` is the default value on `expdp` or I misunderstood ?

Comment: It's what someone with plenty of experience expdp'ing an impdp'ing told me.  But the manual agrees with you.  So, you should use version=>'12' when exporting: "Specify a value of 12 to allow all existing database features, components, and options to be exported from Oracle Database 11g release 2 (11.2.0.3) or later into an Oracle Database 12 c Release 1 (12.1)"  cfr https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_datpmp.htm#ARPLS66053

Comment: This is intresting: `Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Lun Giu 18 15:19:49 2018
UDE-00018: Client Data Pump incompatibile con la versione di database 11.2.0.1.0` and doing the same on the expdp11 `Export: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Jun 18 13:19:14 2018
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39023: Version 12 is not supported.
`

Comment: Oracle's manuals used to be of very good quality.  But I see now: 11.2.0.3 in the manual.

Comment: I saw... i think 11.2.0. **1**  is the problem.

Comment: Do you have the means to upgrade?

Comment: No way but I succesfully managed this with exp/imp and also with sqldeveloper database copy.